# Keeping multiple images centered in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, center

I have been trying to have a grid layout with multiple images. I am trying to keep the margin spacing between images the same and keep the whole group centered into the middle of the page as the page resizes.

In order to keep the images separate I have put a margin of 20 px.
I put col-xx-xx to try to keep things centered but the content tends to shift to the left.

Here is the code:

```css
#fund {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBIwOgafnZrnDssRi0czWu7VKvSLVjbwi2VYsIF3u0QBgGZbFSOw');
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  margin:20px;
}

#fund h3{
  padding-bottom:80px;
}

#fund .btn {
  position: bottom;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="platform">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>A Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>B Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>C Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-centered">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>D Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>E Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>F Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>G Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="fund">
       <h3>H Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" id="fund">
       <h3>I Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" id="fund">
       <h3>J Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" id="fund">
       <h3>K Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" id="fund">
       <h3>L Database</h3>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
       </div>       
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that there should be unique `id`s in each HTML page.  (i.e. `#fund`) - if you want multiple elements (`div`s) to share a common CSS property, use `class`es instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the margin property to auto for left and right side (margin:20px auto;)

```css
#fund {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBIwOgafnZrnDssRi0czWu7VKvSLVjbwi2VYsIF3u0QBgGZbFSOw');
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  margin:20px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body{
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: arial;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  padding: 20px;
}
.col{
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 40px;
  min-width: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #263238;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBIwOgafnZrnDssRi0czWu7VKvSLVjbwi2VYsIF3u0QBgGZbFSOw');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">Image1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">Image2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">Image3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">Image4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aguhsdss/1/

Comment: This is close but when it gets down to just one single column the image boxes are still not centering in the middle of the page.